# Xcode 10 not building latest swift file

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift4, xcode10

I have updated from xcode 9 to xcode 10, after doing so when I try to change the code in one swift file the changes are not reflected when being built. I have tried the following with no success:

(1) Delete Derived Data

(2) Delete the file and re link

(3) Touch the file via terminal

I have tried dozens of solutions with no result. This issue as far as I can tell is only affecting one file. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how do you know the changes are correct? how do you know the new changes are triggered/invoked?

Comment: The changes are simply new lines of code added. I have opened the swift files with another editor and can confirm the changes have gone through.

Comment: that is not a poof of the changes are actually triggered in runtime or does what you expect form them – that is based on speculation from this perspective; I think you need to step back a few and go back to those changes and debug them first before you start blaming Xcode 10...?

Comment: My previous code had a line that read as following:
let a = ["1", "2", "3"] my new code is let a = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]. Xcode is  only printing 1, 2, 3 not 4.

Comment: did you do a clean build?  CMD + SHIFT + ALT + K

Comment: did you put an explicit breakpoint there to see that line is triggered? have your tried `po`d the vars to the console? (making the changes means nothing on its own, it could be in a different target, in a different method, using different localisation, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode10 has incremental compilation mode for the debug builds. This might be affecting it. Check below link
https://shashikantjagtap.net/wwdc18-modern-tips-for-optimising-swift-build-time-in-xcode-10/

Answer (score 0):

There's apparently an issue with the new build system, see [related issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8073#issuecomment-418522858) for details. One way around this is to switch to the legacy build system in `File > Workspace Settings…`.